# Optimizing 1000 regex searches across 10,000 files in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Given a file that has around 1000 individual regex searches that must be applied across 10,000 other files or so, I'm looking for a nice way to make this run in less than a day's time.  No search and replacing going on, just straight match checking.  I can manually go through and combine many of these, but I'm wondering if there is an automated tool to do this and perhaps eveng get it down to a single search.

Also wondering if this hasn't been asked 1000 times as well, but my google-foo is failing me here.

Edit: Using an external tool is a possibilitiy, but this has to be run through a script where those 1000 or so searches as passed though and all the results are prettied up into a nice report.  I have the side of things done in C#, but it is painfully slow, hence the combine idea or other ways of making it go faster.  BTW, I do have it threaded already as well.

Comment: My go-to would be [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) and its command line functionality. It supports Perl regex syntax.

Comment: errrr, grep?  wingrep?

Comment: Built in grep for C#, but honestly, does it matter?  Grep strings anre pretty dang universal and I'd expect there to be some sort of thingy out there for auto joining searches, but not being an expert in the area, I come here to ask.

Comment: And if this closed, I wonder why as I've received no other links with similiar info, just a bunch of threads where people manually combine stuff, the "fun" task I am trying to avoid.  Not to mention if combining searches will make things go much faster - the performance side of things that is driving me to combine the searches in the first place.

Comment: Just wondering - when I read your question I'm thinking that maybe this is one of those situations where one should step back and say, "why am I doing what I'm doing?" Maybe the best solution is to find a completely different way that the whole system should be functioning.

Comment: Did you compile all these regexes? (`RegexOptions.Compiled` and put them into your own list) ?

Comment: Compiling I will try next.  But, I am hoping for orders of magnitude in performance increase and I wonder if this is even possible without some sort of Finite State Machine type solution.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Regex engines use finite state machines too.  What I think you're concerned with is not avoiding using FSM, but having it automatically generated instead of building it by hand.  Which is what `flex` and friends do.

Comment: what kind of code are you using at the moment?   I marked this for closure because you are basically asking for a offsite resource  / there is no one clear answer.... which is exactly the answers you are getting

Comment: Regex.IsMatch(text, regexSearch); within a loop that hits each file and each pattern (all paterns per file to prevent I/O spamming). I inherited a #^$&load of regex searches and needed to make it run x100 faster than the Python-based solution that existed before.  By threading the process so I hit multiple files at once with C#, I got a x10 increase.  The next x10 looks like it may come from the improve search that was created by the PERL script.  If I want another x10, I need to follow @Ben Voigt's wisdom, or hand-code a trie-based search that incorporates every GREP string thus far.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Answers suggesting external tools do not make a question an off-topic request for an off-site resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First place for improvement is to make sure your loops are nested in the right order.

Loop over the files, and for each file, try all 1000 patterns before moving to the next file.  That way you only have to open each file once, not 1000 times.

Second idea is to use a parser generation like flex+yacc+bison to precompile a single DFA (deterministic finite automaton) that covers all the patterns.  In the same way that matching against an entire dictionary can use a trie, matching against a list of patterns can generally be done using a state machine with a lot less computation than matching each pattern separately (basically: where and how one pattern fails to match contains information on what patterns might fit in that region)

Comment: NB: Not all patterns are compilable to DFA. All regular patterns are, but for instance patterns using backreferences aren't

Comment: No back referencing going on in my patterns, so this could be an option.

Comment: Next up, your post reads to me like a foreign language.  I'd not even heard of flex before and yacc/bison sound like UNIXy animals.  After taking a brief trip down google lane here, I admit that I still don't know where to even start with this. :)  I've already created a trie for non-grep searches and that flies at light speed, and I understand how to manually create that which you suggest and turn it into a FSM by hand, but I'm not sure how buffalo-kin are going to pull this plowshare for me so that my grep strings magically become one function or string.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: flex accepts a grammar, which is a bunch of patterns and associated actions.  For your case, the action could be setting a flag (at least one rule matched), setting a global variable (rule number N matched), or calling `push_back` on a vector of matching rules, if you need to identify multiple matches.  You'll also need a non-greedy match-all pattern that has a null action.  `flex` will take that grammar and compile it into a function containing FSM code to actually perform the matching, plus the actions you specified.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Of the top google hits, [this example](http://harishankar.org/blog/entry.php/flex-learning-a-little-bit-of-pattern-matching) looks like the easiest to follow.  It has a catch-all pattern at the end (just `.`), and also examples of flag setting.

Comment: Excellent - I'll look at that this evening, even with my Perl solution below, learning new stuff is always good!

Answer (score 1):

Found something interesting:

Here is a [Regex combiner](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Regexp-Assemble-0.35/Assemble.pm) that runs a Perl script to take all the strings and put them into the One String to rule them all.

Of course, the string that was output from my source strings was roughly 7000 characters in length and that caused C#'s Regex implementaion to blow up spectacularly after roughly 1024 characters - because 1024 characters is all any sane person would need. 2^10 is very magical here.

So who knows if it ran faster after combining because the combination failed too :)

Edit: Hmm, changed a couple of minor things within the search string (removed \ on quotes) and it runs.  Now, time to see if the results of the One String match the results of the 1000 strings.  It does appear to run x10 faster though, which is very nice!

Comment: There is certainly no 1K limit on C# regex strings. I've written a kind of regex "language" that is supposedly more understandable (at least for me) than regex, and it emits a C# regex string, and sometimes they're over 3K.

Comment: Yup - had bad \' characters in there screwing things up.  It's running ok now and much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a big step back, realizing that 99% of the searches could be easily converted into straight string searches with just a little bit of work, and then using a simple hashset search per word.  The remaining searches that needed GREP I left be and it ran plenty fast.  KISS.